# does stm32 timer interrupt process parallelly?

Tags: stm32, mcu

for example, I use   HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1)  to start Outcomparison Interrupt Mode.
considering HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback().Will it process parallelly with commands in the main() or first process interrupt then resume to process in the main()?

Comment: It's not cleear what you mean by "parallely". You are talking about a processor with only one core and no OS, so only one thread is executing at once and there is no scheduling. An interrupt is handled until it exits (or until a more prioritary exception occurs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main context will stop, either between two instructions or occasionally part-way through a multi-part instruction (such as LDM "load-multiple").

The interrupt will run to completion and then the main context will resume.

For more details read section B1.5 of the ARMv7M architecture reference manual: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest (or the equivalent section of the ARMv6M ARM if you are using a Cortex-M0).

Comment: "the interrupt will run to completion" unless there is a more prioritary exception. Also the main context will not resume if another exception is pending at the end of the first exception handler

Comment: Yes, one could also add "unless the power is removed" or "unless the reset signal is asserted", or "unless a bomb destroys the microcontroller core" but these are all just common sense that follow on from what is stated.